# Can I upgrade PostgreSql 10 to PostgreSql 12

Tags: postgresql

I have a ubuntu 18.04 server running PostgreSql 10.

Can I upgrade PostgreSql 10 to PostgreSql 12?
Or i must go first int PostgreSql 11 and then to PostgreSql 12.

Comment: Upgrading a PG cluster is explained in detail in [the official docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/upgrading.html)

Comment: I don't see any reason why you shouldn't be able to. If you want to be super safe you can just do a dump-load operation. What problems did you run into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i use pg_upgrade

pg_upgrade supports upgrades from 8.4.X and later to the current major release of PostgreSQL, including snapshot and beta releases.